# how to know next primary key value of table without inserting record in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

I have a things in my project where i need to display next primary key in field without inserting the record physically?

How can i know the next value of primary key without inserting record?

i.e.
Lets have 10 records with ID columns as primary key.
Now I have deleted 10th record, so the next value will be 11.

I want to know the value of next primary key (11 in my case) without inserting the record physically in the table.

In short, the future next value of the primary key.

How can i get that??

Please provide the solution.

Comment: See it is posible to get the next value without inserting physical record.

Comment: that is **NOT** a valid solution. You can query the **CURRENT** value - but that does not make **ANY GUARANTEE** what the next value will be.....

Comment: This seems like a **really silly requirement** - being able to display something that's not even "real" yet... why on earth would you (or your customer) need that??? You'll need to use the `SEQUENCE` object in SQL Server 2012, there's no reliable other way to do this - but again: **W-H-Y** do you need this!?!?!?!?!??!?

Comment: agree with you @marc_s, but after all client is always right :), I inform him but he is not technical, but i vote the answer and your great comments with some limitation (for me it is work)

Comment: See: [Top 5 Reasons why "The Customer Is Always Right" is wrong](http://positivesharing.com/2006/07/why-the-customer-is-always-right-results-in-bad-customer-service/)

Comment: That's madness. The need to do it indicates a huge flaw in your design.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT (Very important)**

It should be noted that this method can be used to predict the next id, but does not gaurentee this value. The reason for this is as @marc_s mentioned in the comments, that between the time that you requested the value, and the time you use it, another transaction could have inserted into this table, making the assumption of the value retrieved null and void.

As mentioned, if your implementation is based on such an assumption, you have made some design errors, and should look at reworking this solution as a first priority.

From [IDENT_CURRENT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx)

> Returns the last identity value generated for a specified table or
>   view. The last identity value generated can be for any session and any
>   scope.

Have a look at the following example

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        Val INT
)

INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 1
INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 2
INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 3

SELECT * FROM #Table

DELETE FROM #Table WHERE ID >= 2

SELECT * FROM #Table

SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('#Table')

DROP TABLE #Table
```

Comment: This can give you the **current** value - but it makes **no guarantee** as to what the **NEXT** value will be....

Comment: @marc_s this gives you last identity used for that table, so the next would depend on what the identity interval is, which typically is 1, so next would be that +1, me thinks?

Comment: well first of all, an IDENTITY isn't always incremented by 1 - it could be something else. Even if you take that into account - there's **no guarantee** that you will get that value - another transaction could insert a row between the time you query the IDENT_CURRENT, and by the time you're row gets inserted. There just **is no reliable way** to know the next IDENTITY value ahead of time.

Comment: Aggreed on the reliabiltiy. I would never use this to "predict" the next value, as to use this in a relational instance, that would just be utterly silly. Why would you want to predict the value assigned to a child/many relationship. That is what the Database is for, dont try tomaintain something like this in code, you will have eons worth of pain down the road

Comment: exactly - you can **guess** the next value - but not reliably predict it. That's my point. But I agree: why would you even need to **know** that ahead of time, before inserting?? If you need that, your design is fishy to begin with....

Comment: @marc_s I think a BOLD comment in the answer must be inserted, as to notify other OPs of this X-)

Comment: In the event the table is using an increment other than 1, just add `IDENT_INCR('#Table')` like this: `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('#Table') + IDENT_INCR('#Table')`. The usual disclaimers apply: if the system has concurrent usage, the value returned may not match the next ID produced in the session.

Answer (score 5):

What you're asking doesn't really make sense. Databases are designed to support multiple access so even if there was a way to determine the next primary key identity without inserting a record there would be zero guarantee that another connection wouldn't write to that table and claim that identity before your next transaction completes. And if you're thinking "Well I could keep a lock on it" then you've basically eliminated any sort of plausible situation where knowing the future identity key might help you.

So what is your reasoning for wanting the future identity key?

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of SQL Server (2008 R2), and using the `IDENTITY` mechanism, you **CANNOT** know the next value ahead of time. There is **no** proper, guaranteed way to know the next value until you've actually inserted the row - only then, when the row is stored inside the table, that value is determined and returned.

SQL Server 2012 ("Denali") will have `SEQUENCES` which is almost the same as `IDENTITY` columns - but stand-alone, and with sequences, you can ask for the next value (and then use it)

Read more about sequences:

- [SQL Server Denali Sequence Object Overview](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2011/07/sql-server-denali-sequence-object.html)
- [SQL Server v.Next (Denali) : Using Sequences](http://SQL%20Server%20v.Next%20%28Denali%29%20%3a%20Using%20SEQUENCE)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your primary key uses the concept of auto-increment. This means that you can do the following. Get the highest id and add 1 to it.
"id" is unique and uses auto-increment. "table" is your database.

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table
```

This will return the highest id. Just add 1.

Comment: This solution will not always be correct: if keys have been added and removed it might not be the highest id

Answer (score 0):

select IDENT_CURRENT('users')

select IDENT_CURRENT('table name')

Comment: This gives you the **CURRENT** value - but that does tell you for sure what the **NEXT VALUE** will be......

Comment: of course, you are right when there is a big application and doing insertion from many client browser, sorry to mention but i am having very small

Answer (score 0):

Not really a great idea, but if you want a guaranteed primary key my suggestion would be to insert a dummy record temporarily and get its primary key  and then either change the record using UPDATE when the record is committed or DELETE the record if the user cancels insertion. Either way, it's better than using an imaginary key.